# Email notifications system in Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, email, active-record

I'm working on the Rails project where I have many-to-many :through relationship.  Each setting has many notifications through email_notification model where the notification can be primary or a secondary.

`schema.rb`

```
create_table "email_notifications", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "setting_id"
  t.integer "notification_id"
  t.boolean "primary"
  t.boolean "secondary"

create_table "notifications", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"

create_table "settings", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "truck_identification"
  t.string   "email_periods"
  t.integer  "email_recepient_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  t.integer  "truck_fleet_id"
```

In models

```
class EmailNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :notification_id, :setting_id, :primary, :secondary
  belongs_to :notification
  belongs_to :setting



class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :settings, :through => :email_notifications
  has_many :email_notifications
end


class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  # TODO: refactor this bullshit
  attr_accessible :email_periods, :email_recepient_id, :truck_identification, 
                  :truck_fleet_id

  has_many :notifications, :through => :email_notifications
  has_many :email_notifications
  validates_uniqueness_of :truck_fleet_id 
  # validates :email, :email_format => true
end
```

I used this many-to-many relationship because I need flexibility to add up new Notifications over the time, and keep ability to make notifications flexible as possible.  For example, I might add a column `frequency`, or `interval` etc.

Let me know if you can find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
# TODO: refactor this bullshit
```

While amusing to devs, swear words probably don't belong in production code.

In your copypasta of `schema.rb`, I do believe you forgot to paste the `end` keywords.

As a side note, you can also write `null: false` instead of `:null => false`; as far as I can tell, this is the accepted syntax. You can do the same thing with `through: :email_notifications` and anything of the form `Symbol => BasicObject`. This syntax was added after this question was posted, but if you're still interested in updating it, that's what I'd do.

Personally, I prefer to use Symbols instead of Strings as table names, though that's entirely personal preference.

In your models, you also forgot an `end` at the end of your first class.

Aside from that... Well, honestly, it looks good to me. Since I can't really tell what `Setting` and `Notification` are supposed to represent on a more concrete level than their names alone can give, I can't give good advice on how to link them together. However, I don't see why you need a many-to-many, if I'm understanding the purpose of `Setting` and `Notification` correctly. It seems like it could be a one-to-many relationship, though I'm not sure which side should be the one.

Comment: To be fair to OP, `schema.rb` is auto-generated. It's not intended to be edited manually (the spacing is Rails' fault). Also, since it's a 3 year old question, the hashrocket syntax (`=>`) was perhaps the only syntax available at the time. The JSON-like `key: value` syntax didn't appear until Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @Flambino Oh, I wasn't aware that `schema.rb` was autogenerated. I'm just gonna delete that point and pretend it never existed... (And yes, I'm aware of the latter. I had a sentence in there like "It was introduced in 1.9" somewhere but I guess it got lost while I was shuffling around the points in my answer.) Fixed both points.